# Generating a background image from a php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have to generate a background image from a php file and I can't get it to work properly. Here is my situation:

I have a javascript line where I call the php file like this:

```
document.body.style.background = 'url(http:/...../getBackground.php) no-repeat center center fixed';
```

In the getBackground.php file I had to generate the background image from a folder that contains a number (that can change) of images. I did it like this:

```
$dir = 'images/';
$arr = scandir($dir); 
$images = array();
$pattern = '([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)';
foreach($arr as $file){if(preg_match($pattern, $file)){$images[] = $file;}} //get only the images from the folder
$count = count($images);
$i = mt_rand(0, $count - 1); // pick a random image

header("Content-type: image/png"); 
$photo = 'images/' . $images[$i];
$src_img = imagecreatefrompng($photo);
imagepng($src_img);
```

But something is wrong because I don't get the images displayed properly. Can anyone help? What am I missing?

Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Comment: Are you generating images from existing images? Why not just use the existing images?

Comment: Yes, I have to generate from existing images that are located in that specific folder. But the number of images can change. Images can be added or removed from that folder

Comment: Have you manually browsed to `http:/...../getBackground.php` to see if an image was given? This way you know if the fault lies in the PHP script

Comment: Are you sure you have the pathname correct? `images` is a subdirectory of the directory containing the `getBackground.php` script?

Comment: I have triple checked the paths and they are correct. The $photo variable returns the correct path to the files

Comment: You are very specifically outputting png data, but allowing jpg, png, gif and bmp source files. Then, you are recreating the image for every single page load instead of just passing the image data through. See my answer for a tidier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is you are very specifically outputting png data, but allowing jpg, png, gif and bmp source files.

This should be a LOT faster and easier on the server. This does not recreate an image each time, it just passes through the existing image.

```
<?php

   $dir        = 'images';
   $ext        = 'jpg,gif,png'; // List the desired image extensions here, comma separated. 

   $images     = glob($dir.'/*.{'.$ext.'}', GLOB_BRACE);
   $random     = $images[array_rand($images)];
   $image_type = exif_imagetype($random);

   header("Content-type: " . image_type_to_mime_type($image_type));
   readfile($random);

?>
```

Comment: You are right. I tried out you solution and it works perfectly. Thanks